# NextJS share dynamic menu with pages with data fetched from DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to fetch menu items from my db with api call and fill my navigation component inside my nextjs app.

I don't want to use `getInitiaProps` because deprecated in my _app.js, what is the right strategy?

this is my `_app.js` file, I need to keep navigation outside my `Layout` component because there is a page transition on each page. Any ideas?

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation/Navigation";
import FooterPanel from "../components/FooterPanel/FooterPanel";
import { settings } from "../settings/settings";
import DarkModeSwitch from "../components/DarkModeSwitch/DarkModeSwitch";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  const layoutType = Component.layout || settings.layouts.standard;

  /* fetch data for navigation */

  const menu = ???? HO TO FETCH ???


  return (
    <>
      <Navigation menu={menu}/>
      <Layout type={layoutType} router={router}>
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.asPath} router={router} />
      </Layout>
      <DarkModeSwitch classes="fixed bottom-5 md:bottom-20 right-0 z-10 mr-4" />
      <FooterPanel />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: If you want to render the menu with SSR on every page you can use `getInitialProps` in `_app.js`

Comment: Or you can add getServersideProps / getStaticprops on each page of your app and fetch it there

Answer (score 0):

There may be better alternatives but this is something I would definitely give a try.

I didn't use your Navigation component because initially I wanted to make sure it works with pure html elements.

It will make an async call with each page navigation, let us ignore it for now and focus on what matters.

_app.js

```
const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([]);

const getMenuItems = async () => {
  let data;
  // async code to fetch menu items from db and fill data variable
  setMenuItems(data);
};

useEffect(() => {
  getMenuItems();
}, [router.asPath]);

return (
  <>
    <nav>
      {menuItems.map((link, index) => {
        return (
          <ul>
            <Link href={link.path}>
              <li key={index}>{link.name}</li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        );
      })}
    </nav>
    <Layout type={layoutType} router={router}>
      <Component {...pageProps} key={router.asPath} router={router} />
    </Layout>
    <DarkModeSwitch classes="fixed bottom-5 md:bottom-20 right-0 z-10 mr-4" />
    <FooterPanel />
  </>
);
```